# how to fix FileNotFoundError Errno 2 no such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.6

i have gone through some of the solutions provided but it doesn;t help me. Please someone tell me what im missing

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
import os.path

bot = ChatBot('Cuibot') 
bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)

for files in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\AMINDE64\\Chat\\chatterbot-corpus- 
1.1.2\\chatterbot_corpus\\data\\english'): 
data = open('C:\\Users\\AMINDE64\\chat\\chatterbot-corpus- 
1.1.2\\chatterbot_corpus\\data\\english' + files, "r").readlines()
bot.train(data)

while True:
    message = input('You:')
    if message.strip() != 'Bye':
    reply = bot.get_response(message)
               print('ChatBot :', reply) 
    if message.strip() == 'Bye':
    print('ChatBot : Bye')
   break
```

Comment: This is the error i get                                                                              
 .                                               
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\AMINDE64\\chat\\chatterbot-corpus-1.1.2\\chatterbot_corpus\\data\\englishai.yml'

Comment: I think you're missing a final \\ in data\\english' + files. Edit: it's tough to format code properly like that in comments. You need another double backslash at the end of the string.

Comment: Also, you've added the error in the comments. You can see that the file name is getting concatenated to the last directory. You should pay attention to the error messages as you can see the issue straight away: `englishai.yml` when you're trying to access `english/ai.yml`

Comment: Thank you very much for the enlightenment and yes i did see the concatenation at the end

Answer (score 1):

First, make the code a little bit more readable, e.g.:

```
dirname = 'C:\\Users\\AMINDE64\\Chat\\chatterbot-corpus- 
    1.1.2\\chatterbot_corpus\\data\\english'

for filename in os.listdir(dirname): 
    data = open(dirname + filename, "r").readlines()
    bot.train(data)
```

Now it is readable, but still doesn't work.

Then, use `os.path.join` to join the path, use `with` to make sure the file is propperly closed:

```
for filename in os.listdir(dirname): 
    with open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), "rt") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    bot.train(data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, its good to go now!! You just made my!!@ zvone

Comment: Thank you very much, its good to go now!! You just made my!!@ zvone

Comment: Thank you for the debugging but now that i have applied it, it seems to list the trainer properly and then at a point it stops and returns this error message  as below

Comment: `**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AMINDE64\Chat\chatbot_train.py", line 12, in <module>
    data = f.readlines()
  File "C:\Users\AMINDE64\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 3452: character maps to <undefined>**`

Comment: @Kalyan maybe a demonstration will do. i did try to use it and it returned an error, so im guessing i didn't use it properly. Also i did check if the encoding on sublime text was at utf-8 and yes it is

Comment: In open function, use an argument for encoding